# Ask a user for several values in VSCode extension

Tags: typescript, promise, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing a VSCode extension, and I would like to do the following thing:

- Ask user for a first value (through `window.showInputBox()`
- Ask user for a second value
- Perform an action using the first and second value

I came up with a quick and dirty solution:

```
function askForFirstValue() { 

  window.showInputBox(options).then(value => { 
    firstValue = value; 
    askForSecondValue(); 
  }); 
} 

function askForSecondValue() { 

  window.showInputBox(options).then(value => { 
    secondValue = value; 
    performAction(firstValue, secondValue);
  }); 
}
```

Obviously, this is less than ideal. I am trying to implement a nicer solution with a more generic function:

```
function askUserForValue(prompt: string, placeholder: string) {
    let options: InputBoxOptions = {
        prompt: prompt,
        placeHolder: placeholder
    }

    return window.showInputBox(options)
}
```

Then I would do:

```
var firstValue = null
var secondValue = null
firstValue = askUserForValue(/*something*/)
secondValue = askUserForValue(/*something*/)
performAction(firstValue, secondValue);
```

But when I do this, the prompt close immediatly after opening and the `performAction` function is called as `firstValue` and `secondValue` are still `null`.

I understand that this has to do with how promises work, and I tried several way of handling those promises, but I am new at Javascript/Typescript and I feel like I am going nowhere.

Comment: Adding the keyword [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) before `askUserForValue` should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

HaaLeo suggestion was helpful, but it didn't exactly work as mentionned.
This is how I did it:

```
askUserForValues().then(value => {
    performAction(value);
});

async function askUserForIrcInstance() {
    var firstValue = await askUserForValue(/*something*/)
    var secondValue = await askUserForValue(/*something*/)
    return new myObject(firstValue, secondValue );
}
```